# Bullet char appears instead of space char in my password, while i'm rewording it, while it's hidden and how to stop bullet char entering my input?

Tags: password-protection

The problem is the following:

- When I type sequence of "space" chars in the password field,
  and then delete the first "space" char from the sequence while hidden (the sequence of space chars can be anywhere in the string). It shows a bullet char, instead of space when I reveal the password.

On the screenshot below you can see in the console, it prints some "bullet" char which I don't know where it comes from.

The password requirement that says: "Cannot start or end with white space",
is made with regex and works! But in this weird example, the "space" char changes to "bullet"
and thus making the regex not working.

You can test it here - https://milovanmilovanov.github.io/Login-form/

type sequence of spaces followed with letters, then delete the first "space" char while the password is hidden. And the "Cannot start or end with white space" validation will fail. Thanks :)!

[image]